# Changing parameter order of the function given to map

Tags: haskell

Say for example we had a function

```
divide :: Float -> Float -> Float
divide x y = x / y
```

And a list `let list = [1,2,3]`

I know i can apply the divide function to the list like so: `map (divide 3) temp`

But what if I wanted to swap the order of the parameters passed to the `divide` method, so that each element of the list is divided by 3, rather than 3 being divided by the element.

Something like the following `map (divide temp) 3`.

Additionally, what if `divide` had 3 parameters and each element of the list needed to be the middle parameter. How would one do this?

Comment: For the two parameter case, prelude has ```flip```.

Comment: To make @ArtYerkes comment explicit, `map (flip divide 3) temp` does what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use `divide` as an infix-operator by enclosing it in backtics like this

```
map (`divide` 3) temp
```

or, if you run into a more complicated case in the future, write a lambda (anonymous function)

```
map (\x -> divide x 3) temp
```

You may also want to take a look at this more detailed explanation https://wiki.haskell.org/Anonymous_function

Answer (score 1):

Just make the function parameter an explicit lambda instead of a partially applied function:

```
map (\n -> divide n 3) temp
```